# Why not use Object for all method parameters?

Tags: java, variables, parameter-passing

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello World";
        l(text);
        int n = 0;
        l("--------------------------");
        l(n);   
    }

    public static void l(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

I wrote this simple program in Java and it worked. Now I am confused that if all the data types (`int`, `char`, `double` etc.) come under `Object`, then why do we specify which data type we want to accept when we pass values?

I mean we can always use the data type `Object` as used in the function `l`. Is there a specific reason why people don't always use `Object` as their data type to pass values?

Comment: `int` is not an `Object`. It is being autoboxed to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion defined between all primitive types and their respective object counterparts:

```
int -> Integer
char -> Character
etc...
```

This is called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

> Is there a specific reason why people don't always use "Object" as their data type to pass values?

Since Java is strongly typed, you cannot do a whole lot with [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

E.g. try this:

```
static Object add(Object a, Object b) {
    return a + b; // won't compile
}
```

This is because methods, operators, etc. available to use depend on the static type of the variable.

`println` can accept `Object` because it only needs to call the `toString` method. If you *only* need the limited functionality provided by the methods in `Object`, then sure, you can use it as a type. This is rarely the case, however.

Answer (score 8):

For the primitives you mentioned, they are not really objects, they will simply be boxed to their representation as an object. An `int` would become an `Integer`, a `long` would become a `Long` etc.

Read this article about [Autoboxing in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

As for your question

> Is there a specific reason why people don't always use "Object" as
>   their data type to pass values?

If you specify `Object` as the parameter of your method you won't be able to call the methods the real object contains without doing a cast. For example, if you have a custom object `AnyObject` that contains a method `anyMethod`, you won't be able to call it without casting the object to `AnyObject`.

It will also be unsafe as you will be able to pass any type of object to a method which may not be designed to function properly with any of these types. A method containing only `System.out.println` is not representative of a real use case, it will work with any object simply because by default the `println` will call the `toString` method which is already defined in an `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

While it does look like a function that appears to accept all types of parameters, you will have to deal with these

- The function signature becomes less informative.
- No more overloading
- You have to do a lot of type checking and casting in the function body to avoid run time errors.
- Although the method seemingly accepts all objects, you would never know the actual subset of them until you see the method definition.
- The function body might end up having more code to eliminate the wrong types than for its real goal. For example, your function only prints the value. Imagine a function that predominantly does some integer operation.
- Increases the probability of run time errors, as the compiler cannot throw errors for missing casts.